# Concatenar cadenas con un bucle while y for anidado en Java

Tags: java, bucles, concatenación

Estoy atascado con un ejercicio, quiero mostrar la cadena "*|*1|*12|*123|*1234" para ello debo usar un `while` y un `for` anidados da igual el orden.

```
public class Ejercicio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cad = "";
        int numero = 4; //*|*1|*12|*123|*1234
        while (1 <= numero) { 
            for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++ ){
                cad += i;
                cad += "|*";
           } 
           numero--;
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo este código por el momento, pero no consigo obtener el `output` que quiero. ¿Alguna orientación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Que tal? tuviste un error en el manejo de la variable numero, estás decrementando tu variable inicial (numero), esa variable no la tenes que tocar, y además primero empezas por las subcadenas más largas y las vas achicando (queda al revés de como te lo dice el ejercicio).

La concatenación esta mal, en tu código está insertando el "|*" por cada número en lugar de insertarlo por cada subcadena de números. En ese código tu salida quedaría algo como esto:
1|*2|*3|*4|*1|*2|*3|*1|*2|*1

```
public class Ejercicio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cadena = new String("*");
        int numero = 4; //*|*1|*12|*123|*1234

        int num = 1;
        while (num <= numero) { 
            cadena += "|*";
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++ )
                cadena += i;
            num ++;

        }
        System.out.println(cadena);
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya sido útil

Comment: Gracias por la solución, fácil de entender.

Answer (score 0):

Orientación:

1. **Inicializa tu cad con el caracter que no forma parte del patrón** "|*+{serie de números del 1 al maxSerie}" que se repite. Es decir el *
2. **Tu variable numero corresponde al número de veces que se repite la serie** (pero cada vez aumentando el maxSerie en una unidad). Este numero de veces que se repite la serie se controla con el while externo y el uso de la variable numero y su comparación con un indice (que creo te falta).
3. **El for interno construye el patrón con el uso de un indice y su comparación con maxSerie**.
4. **Organiza tu código** ya que es dificil de seguir. Por ejemplo, para las comparaciones de variables con constantes escribe la variable a la izquierda. **Indenta correctamente tu código**. **Da nombres claros y representativos a tus variables** (el nombre debe indicar a primera vista su función).

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que vos queres hacer:

```
String cad = "";
int numero = 4; //*|*1|*12|*123|*1234
int j =numero-2;
while (j >= -1) { 
    cad += "|*";
    for (int i = 1; i < numero-j; i++ ){
         cad += i;
    }
    j--; 
}
System.out.println(cad);
```

Comment: Exactamente, muchas gracias.